# Multiply a layer with 1 output to a layer with multiple outputs

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I am trying to get the neural network to multiply two input tensors (I cannot do it before feeding them into the network). Keras' `multiply` function can only handle two tensors of the same dimension. Have something like:

```
scale_, mean_ = 2., 4.
a = Input(shape=(300,), name='Input_vec')
m_num = Input(shape=(1,), name='Input_num')
mulNum = Lambda(lambda x: K.exp(x * scale_ + mean_))(m_num)
output = multiply([mulNum, a]) # tensors not same shape
```

how can I do the multiplication of two inputs where one is just a scalar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tf.multiply()` (or `tf.math.multiply()`) that supports broadcasting:

```py
output = Lambda(lambda x: tf.multiply(x[0], x[1]))((a, mulNum))
```

Comment: You shoud give inputs to the Lambda layer, else an error will pop.